# как сделать при повторном нажатии обратное действие?

Tags: javascript

Как при повторном нажатии на кнопку отменить действие или добавить функцию которая будет возращать данные элементы обратно на места?
Собственно перенос элементов происходит при нажатии поменять местами на данном сайте [serjo96.github.io/matrix](http://serjo96.github.io/matrix)

```
 $(document).on("click",".change-mtrx", function(){
  $('.matrix_a').appendTo('.matrix_b_cover');
  $(".matrix_b").appendTo(".matrix_a_cover");
});
```

Comment: какое действие ты должен отменить (на примере)? А так на текущий момент все рулит состояниями, например в ReactJS это Redux с Immutable моделью. Там легко отматывать назад события

Comment: Отменить перенос элементов которые происходят при клике

Comment: добавьте в вопрос начальную html разметку, чтобы было видно где находятся `.matrix_a`,`.matrix_b`, `.matrix_b_cover`,  `.matrix_a_cover` и куда они должны вернуться

Comment: Добавил ссылку на проект

Comment: Добавьте разметку **непосредственно** в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавлять и убирать вспомогательный класс. И проверять его наличие.

```js
  $('.change-mtrx').click(function () {
    var matrixA = $('.matrix_a');
    var matrixB = $('.matrix_b');
    if (!matrixA || !matrixB) return false;

    if (matrixA .hasClass('moved')) {
      matrixA.appendTo($('.matrix_a_cover'));
      matrixA.removeClass('moved');
    } else {
      matrixA.appendTo($('.matrix_b_cover'));
      matrixA.addClass('moved');
    };
    if (matrixB.hasClass('moved')) {
      matrixB.appendTo($('.matrix_b_cover'));
      matrixB.removeClass('moved');
    } else {
      matrixB.appendTo($('.matrix_a_cover'));
      matrixB.addClass('moved');
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="matrix_a_cover"><p>matrix_a_cover</p></div>
<div class="matrix_a"><p>matrix_a</p></div>
<div class="matrix_b_cover"><p>matrix_b_cover</p></div>
<div class="matrix_b"><p>matrix_b</p></div>

<button class="change-mtrx">change-mtrx</button>
```

Comment: очень плохо делаешь, надо повторно вызываемую выборку элементов запиливать в переменную, а так ты по 5 раз ищешь 2 элемента на странице, как думаешь это хорошо?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Согласен. Спасибо за правку.

Comment: А если еще проще сделать, toggleclass на кнопку которую жмем и после устроить проверку сия класса и  далее перенос?

Comment: @Drop Главное, чтобы решение соответствовало механике. Если все блоки меняются хором, а кнопочка одна и после перемещения блоков меняет цвет, то логично использовать класс на кнопке. Если блоками управляет несколько кнопок и после перемещения у блоков меняется отступ, фон или ещё что-то в стилях, то напрашивается класс для блоков.

Comment: @Drop Увидел ссылку на проект. Если в http://serjo96.github.io/matrix/js/style.js заменить `$(document).on("click",".change-mtrx", function(){       $('.matrix_a').appendTo('.matrix_b_cover');  $(".matrix_b").appendTo(".matrix_a_cover"); });` на код из ответа, то переключатель заработает в обе стороны.

Comment: Сделал чуть по проще 

$(document).on("click",".change-mtrx", function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('flipped')) {
    $('.matrix_a').appendTo('.matrix_a_cover');
    $(".matrix_b").appendTo(".matrix_b_cover");
  } else {
    $('.matrix_a').appendTo('.matrix_b_cover');
    $(".matrix_b").appendTo(".matrix_a_cover");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});